# How to connect to Websocket API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

The API I am trying query from is: https://socket.etherdelta.com

Documentation for the API here:https://github.com/etherdelta/etherdelta.github.io/blob/master/docs/API.md

When I try to to do a simple get request: https://socket.etherdelta.com/getmarkets it gives me an error message saying "Cannot GET /getmarkets"

This is the code I am trying to use to get market information:

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'https://socket.etherdelta.com/getMarket';


request(url , (err, res, body) => {
try{
var json = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(json);


}catch(err){
console.log('parsing error');
console.log(body);
}
});
```

edited it to this:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://socket.etherdelta.com')

ws.onopen = function(){
ws.send(JSON.stringify("getMarket"))

};

ws.onmessage = function(msg){
var response = JSON.parse(msg.data);
console.log(response);
};
```

Comment: Example code is in repo: https://github.com/etherdelta/etherdelta.github.io/blob/master/bots/service.js You need to send event and wait for repsponse.

Comment: @hya I am wondering specifically how to get the market data. Do you think you could guide me on how to get that?

Comment: why dont you use the standard 'socket.io' library?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this API operates on WSS protocol rather than HTTPS. Could you please try a web socket client library like [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) with below URL

> wss://socket.etherdelta.com

Comment: hey so updated my code using the ws protocol and still running into errors. Do you see anything blatently wrong with the updated code?

Comment: Hi, I too tried your code and end up getting 520 as response. I saw they have github issue tracker, can you post your question to that community and see because 520 error meant there was error in server side according to my knowledge. Sorry i couldn't help you more.